# Dynamically Updating URL When Creating Divs Using For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert the user before a URL redirect and I am using [SweetAlert.js](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) to achieve that. However I want the URL to dynamically update based on the information present in my JSON data.

If you click on 'Load List' in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8kevczc/), it will append 2 divs to the body. But the URLs that are attached to the 'Website' links are the same. They need to be updated based on the Title of each div which is being pulled from JSON data. If you try clicking the 'Website' in both divs, it leads to the same URL (and the URL is correct for the second div, but not the first div).

See line 36 in my JSFiddle. That's the part I need help with.

Here's my JS code:

```
function createList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.myData.length; i++) {
        myData.push(data.myData[i]);
        myDataTitle = myData[i].Title;
        var list = document.createElement('div');
        list.className = 'unit';
        list.innerHTML =
            '<h2>' + myDataTitle + '</h2>' +
            '<h3>' + myData[i].Description + '</h3>' +
            '<div class="my-options">' +
            '<h4 id="url" onclick="redirectWarning();">Website</h4>'
        '</div>';
        document.body.appendChild(list);
    }
}

function redirectWarning() {
    swal({
        title: 'Redirect?',
        text: 'If you click "OK", you will be redirected.',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true
    }, function () {
        window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=' + myDataTitle, '_blank');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8kevczc/1/)

What you are missing is that the variable `myDataTitle` will have a value of the last element from the loop. That's why on the click element you need to pass the title as parameter to the function `redirectWarning()`.

Also bear in mind that you could have troubles with quoted text.

```
function createList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.myData.length; i++) {
        myData.push(data.myData[i]);
        myDataTitle = myData[i].Title;
        var list = document.createElement('div');
        list.className = 'unit';
        list.innerHTML =
            '<h2>' + myDataTitle + '</h2>' +
            '<h3>' + myData[i].Description + '</h3>' +
            '<div class="my-options">' +
            '<h4 id="url" onclick="redirectWarning(\''+myDataTitle+'\');">Website</h4>'
        '</div>';
        document.body.appendChild(list);
    }
}


function redirectWarning(title) {
    swal({
        title: 'Redirect?',
        text: 'If you click "OK", you will be redirected.',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true
    }, function () {
        window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=' + title, '_blank');
    });
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thank you for the fix! But yeah the quotes to make it a bit complicated.